# running ansible playbook from python with subprocess.run doesnt pass extra vars

Tags: python, ansible, subprocess

so i'm trying to run an ansible playbook from python with subprocess.run, the line im using is :

```
dns = "10.10.10.10"
subprocess.run(["ansible-playbook", f"{playbook_path}", f'-e "os_type=linux"', f'-i {dns},'])
```

and i'm getting

```
fatal: [10.10.10.10]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'os_type == 'linux'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (os_type == 'linux'): 'os_type' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/chaos_project/playbook': line 7, column 11, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      block:\n        - name: Create a directory if it does not exist\n          ^ here\n"}
```

as if os_type isnt defined, but when i just run it as a terminal command it works just fine :

```
ansible-playbook playbook -e 'os_type=linux' -i 10.10.10.10,
```

Comment: Try [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python_interface.html#usage-examples).

Comment: Remove the double qoute from the os_type=linux,

Try this:
subprocess.run(["ansible-playbook", f"{playbook_path}", f'-e os_type=linux', f'-i {dns},'])

Answer (score 0):

eventually im using ansible-runner, but for an easy fix :

```
subprocess.run(["ansible-playbook", f"{playbook_path}", f'-e os_type=linux', f'-i {dns},'])
```

worked fine.